# Visual Studio WPF window height auto no funciona

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión y deseo que su alto se ajuste automáticamente. Para ello hice lo siguiente:

```
<Window x:Class="PrimeraInterfaz.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrimeraInterfaz"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Acceso - Iniciar Sesion" Height="Auto" Width="376" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <Label Content="Usuario" Padding="0,5,0,5"/>
    <TextBox Height="25"/>
    <Label Content="Password" Padding="0,5,0,5"/>
    <TextBox Height="25"/>
    <Grid Margin="0,20,0,10">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Button Content="CANCELAR" />
        </WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content="INICIAR SESION" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Agregue la propiedad `Height="Auto"` para que pueda ajustarse automáticamente y en el diseñador sale bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago correr el programa no sale como en el diseñador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El auto no es muy buen compañero depende de donde lo metas para lograr el efecto deseado, añade lo siguiente en la etiqueta window:

```
SizeToContent="Height"
```

Esto hace que tenga en cuenta él contendió en l'altura. Nota solo escoge l'opción del parámetro que tiene el auto para usarlo.

El codigo resultante seria así:

```
<Window x:Class="PrimeraInterfaz.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrimeraInterfaz"
mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Acceso - Iniciar Sesion" Height="Auto" Width="376" SizeToContent="Height" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <Label Content="Usuario" Padding="0,5,0,5"/>
    <TextBox Height="25"/>
    <Label Content="Password" Padding="0,5,0,5"/>
    <TextBox Height="25"/>
    <Grid Margin="0,20,0,10">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Button Content="CANCELAR" />
        </WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content="INICIAR SESION" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

El resultado :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona, gracias!